# SQL Function for String manipulation

Tags: sql-server

What is the best way to remove the first comma from the following string? The result should be 'TEST,e,er,t'

```
DECLARE @source VARCHAR(100)
SET @source = ',TEST,e,er,t'
```

**EDIT**: what is the best way to remove all the leading commas, if there are more than one comma?

Thanks

Lijo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally I like [T-SQL's STUFF() function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188043.aspx) for this. One of the main reasons is that I don't have to care about how long the string can be, swap out 8000 for 4000 if it is NVARCHAR, etc.

```
SELECT STUFF(@source, 1, 1, '');
```

**EDIT** for new/changed requirements we might need to use SUBSTRING after all:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(@source, PATINDEX('%[^,]%', @source), 8000);
```

[Note that this will return all the commas if the string contains nothing but commas.]

You can of course do this with STUFF() still:

```
SELECT STUFF(@source, 1, PATINDEX('%[^,]%', @source)-1, '');
```

However this will return NULL for a string that is all commas, so you may want to wrap it in a COALESCE() if NULL is undesirable.

Comment: I agree. One more question, what is the best way to remove all the leading commas?

Answer (score 1):

No need to evaluate LEN...

```
SUBSTRING(@source, 2, 8000)
```

Comment: You mean SELECT SUBSTRING(@source, 2, LEN(@source)) is generic solution. However, put a hard coded value instead of using LEN, right?

Comment: @Lijo: no, I mean use 8000. It doesn't add extra spaces at the end and it doesn't change the length. Why evalute LEN? What value does it add? And If you had trailing spaces, you'd lose them with LEN

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @source VARCHAR(100);
SELECT @source = ',TEST,e,er,t';

SELECT @source = SUBSTRING(@source, 2, LEN(@source) - 1);
```

The best way would be if you could take advantage of how the string is being built so that the delimiter doesn't get placed there to begin with.

Comment: Why evaluate LEN? It will remove trailing spaces which may be needed (or may not) of course...

Comment: It can be hard to control the building of the string - it may be done in some other application, it may be done using `FOR XML PATH`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `STUFF`

```
DECLARE @source VARCHAR(100);
SELECT @source = ',TEST,e,er,t';

PRINT STUFF(@source,1,1,'')
```